# Directives that is used in ng-include doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-include

I have custom directive as following.

```
var fancySelectDirective = pluginDirecitvesModule.directive("custom-select",function(){
         return { 
           restrict: 'C',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                  element.fancySelect();
            }
        }
     });
```

This directive is used in template. When I include this template with ng-include , the directive  don't work , that is  the link function don't invoked ( I  try to debug in console ).  but When I use this template directly in page  , the directive works.  I can't  find why this problem occurs.

I use ng-include  as following :

```
<div id="main_wrapper" ng-include="template.html"></div>
```

The  directive is used in template as  following:

```
<select class="custom-select">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just a typo `customSelect` instead of `custom-select`.

Directive should be declared as a camel case & the caps letter will be replaced by `-` + small letter, eg. `customSelect` will written on html as `custom-select`

**Code**

```
var fancySelectDirective = pluginDirecitvesModule.directive("customSelect", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.fancySelect();
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this could help you, Thanks.